# strange results after pulling data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting some unusual results after processing some data retrieved from a `MySQL` table.

I have four fields of type float, two rows. All data is the same as you can see below:

```
Field1 = 5.0, 0.5
Field2 = 5.0, 0.5
Field3 = 5.0, 0.5
Field4 = 5.0, 0.5
```

I retrieve the data like so:

```
// Get ratings for this event
$eventRating = $event->getEventRatings($event_id);

$organisation = 0;
$valueForMoney = 0;
$facilities = 0;
$funFactor = 0;
$overall = 0;



foreach($eventRating AS $rating){
    $organisation   = ($organisation + $rating['organisation']);
    $valueForMoney  = ($ValueForMoney + $rating['value_for_money']);
    $facilities     = ($facilities + $rating['facilities']);
    $funFactor  = ($funFactor + $rating['fun_factor']);
}


// Get average of each rating category

var_dump($organisation      = $organisation /$ratingCount);
var_dump($valueForMoney             = $valueForMoney /$ratingCount);
var_dump($facilities        = $facilities /$ratingCount);
var_dump($funFactor         = $funFactor /$ratingCount);
```

So the results should all be the same right?

But the results of var_dump are:

> float(2.75) float(2.5) float(2.75) float(2.75)

Why is `$valueForMoney`  2.5 when it should be 3?

Answer (score 1):

It might just be a typo in the question, but you've got

```
$valueForMoney  = ($ValueForMoney + $rating['value_for_money']);
```

PHP is case sensitive, so you probably meant...

```
$valueForMoney  = ($valueForMoney + $rating['value_for_money']);
```

With a small "v" after the equals?

Comment: $valueForMoney (small v) will always just be equal to the last $rating['value_for_money'] value (as $ValueForMoney (big V) is always zero). So I'm guessing your last rating was the 5 (and not the 0.5)?